# exception in thread 'main is displayed' when using karateConfig.js

Tags: karate

I was trying to setup karate. while i'm trying to login to the application the following error is displayed. please have a look at the config file and let me know if mistakes are made and also have a look at the feature file which is included below

exception in thread 'main is displayed' when using karateConfig.js

following is the config file

```
function fn() {    
  var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'dev';
  }
  var config = {
        env : env,
    BaseURL : 'URL',
    username : 'XXXX',
    password : 'XXXX',
  };
  if (env == 'dev') {
    config.BaseURL: 'DevURL'
    config.username: 'XXXXX'
    config.password: 'XXXXX'
  } else if (env == 'e2e') {
   console.log('Wrong env')
  }
  return config;
}
```

following is the feature file

```
Feature: login into dev

  Background: 

    * url BaseURL

    Scenario: login with admin credentials

      Given 'XXXX' + 'login'
      And form field username = username
      And form field password = password
      When method POST
      Then status 200
```

following is the error when running the login.feature

```
    18:31:30.662 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - evaluation of 'karate-config.js' failed: javascript evaluation failed: read('classpath:karate-config.js'), javascript evaluation failed: function() {    
      var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
      karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
      if (!env) {
        env = 'dev7';
      }
      var config = {
            env : env,
        BaseURL : 'URL',
        username : 'XXXX',
        password : 'XXXX',
      };
      if (env == 'dev') {
        config.BaseURL: 'devURL'
        config.username: 'XXXX'
        config.password: 'XXXX'
      } else if (env == 'e2e') {
       console.log('Wrong env')
      }
      return config;
}, <eval>:14:18 Expected ; but found :
    config.BaseURL: 'URL'
                  ^ in <eval> at line number 14 at column number 18
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioExecutionUnit.init(ScenarioExecutionUnit.java:147)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioExecutionUnit.run(ScenarioExecutionUnit.java:236)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureExecutionUnit.run(FeatureExecutionUnit.java:164)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureExecutionUnit.run(FeatureExecutionUnit.java:73)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.Engine.executeFeatureSync(Engine.java:109)
    at com.intuit.karate.IdeUtils.exec(IdeUtils.java:64)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:36)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config you have confused JSON with JS, so please make this change all across:

```
config.BaseURL = 'devURL';
```

Also:

> Given 'XXXX' + 'login'

This doesn't make any sense at all. I suggest you read the docs and then follow the quick start: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart - first get that working and then advance from there.